# Java AffinetransformOp filter() screws up my image

Tags: java, image, filter, rotation, affinetransform

I am trying to rotate a 32 by 64 png image with 90 degree increments by using `Affinetransform.rotate(`) and `AffinetransformOp.filter`. It works fine for 0, 90 and 180 degrees but at 270 degrees only half of my image is shown. After some research i found out that this is due to the way `filter()` handles image coordinates but i have no idea how to solve this. I have already tried using other methods to rotate images but i'd rather use this one.

The method for rotating images:

```
public BufferedImage rotateImage(BufferedImage img, double angle) {
    AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();
    tx.rotate(angle, img.getWidth() - 16, img.getHeight() - 16);
    AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx,
            AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
    return op.filter(img, null);
}
```

I also have a screenshot for clarifying my problem:
[image]

**EDIT:** I have tried manually creating a destination image for `filter()` by adding the following code, to no avail.

```
int w, h;
if (angle == Math.PI / 2 || angle == 3 * Math.PI / 2) {
        w = img.getHeight();
        h = img.getWidth();
} else {
        w = img.getWidth();
        h = img.getHeight();
}
BufferedImage dest = new BufferedImage(w, h, img.getType());
return op.filter(img, dest);
```

Comment: I also wish to find a work around for this. When I have a 100x50 size image, rotate it, then filter it, the ending image is 100x100. The process enlarges the image boundaries to paint all of the image, but I would like to know if I can readjust those boundaries once it is done.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has something to do with the fact that you are passing

```
tx.rotate(angle, img.getHeight() / 2 - 16, img.getHeight() - 16);
```

when it should be

```
tx.rotate(angle, img.getWidth() - 16, img.getHeight() / 2 - 16);
```

(you passed getHeight() twice and I'm pretty sure they were in the wrong order)

Let me know if this changes things for you.

Comment: I was indeed using the wrong arguments, so i fixed that. It didn't solve my problem though.